# Unable to convert String to date, Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, android, datetime, exception

I am passing `dateInString` as "`2015-07-30T14:30:00-04:00`". But 
it is throwing

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2015-07-30T14:30:00-04:00" (at offset 0)

Here is the sample code:

```
        private Date convertStringToDate(String dateInString){
        if(dateInString!=null){
            Date convertedDate=null;
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
            formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
            try {
                convertedDate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return convertedDate;
        }
        else
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Is SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy") equals "2015-07-30T14:30:00-04:00"?

Comment: Please read http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/ - and note that the string you pass into the `SimpleDateConstructor` isn't just random junk...

Comment: @cwfei: It's not really a duplicate of that. It's a duplicate of various other questions in terms of "I used SimpleDateFormat without reading the documentation or checking the pattern I was passing in" but that question is more "I don't know about SimpleDateFormat at all".

Comment: @JonSkeet how accurate are you, peace

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing me to the right direction. I will read more about SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. Here is the date format-

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

Thanks everyone for your time :-)